# askopenfilename tkinter functions and globals

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I'm trying to do something to let the users of my company to change their default signature of the email with some personalization.

So I don't understand why when I click this button:

```
 Button(master, text='Insert  Image',command=insert_image).grid(row=12,column=1,sticky=W,pady=4)
```

It calls this:

```
global image_path

def insert_image():
    image_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="X:\\", title="Select the image you want to add")
    image_path = 'X:\\' + str(image_path)
```

It lets me choose the file and it seems to store it in the variable, but later, when I have to use the variable here:

```
    if image_path != "":
        signature.write('<br><br><img src="{}" alt="prova"><br><br>\n'.format(image_path))
```

It gives

```
NameError: name 'image_path' is not defined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create your variable in global scope and then use [`global`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4693120/use-of-global-keyword-in-python) inside your function.

```
image_path = ""

def insert_image():
    global image_path
    image_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(...)
    ...
```